# Grab all network traffic with phantomjs

Tags: web-scraping, phantomjs

I want to use phantomjs to grap all incoming traffic.
Example when a page contains some animations needs a click to load other content or links to click, so my goal is :

1- automate all user events

2- load all the incoming traffic (css, images, js ...)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use onRequestReceived method provided by phantomjs. This will log all static resource requests, ajax calls and normal http calls.

```
page.onResourceRequested = function(response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
};
```

Comment: It's not possible to log the contents of the responses with PhantomJS.

Comment: i tried onLoadFinished but it takes a while without any results

Comment: i'm trying to write a script that behave as httpfox.